# Download File From Website with URL Authentifikation C#

Tags: c#, html, authentication, download, html-agility-pack

I am trying to download a file from one of this sites:

- 1cloudfile
- bowfiles
- games-database

Mainly [games-database.com](https://games-databases.com)

I think all of this sites are using a similar System

For example [games-database.com](https://games-databases.com):
An example link: https://games-database.com/1JD4
There is one button on this website that opens a new window with a link

```
<button style="margin-bottom: 30px;" class="btn btn--primary type--uppercase" onclick="window.location = 'https://games-database.com/1JD4?pt=ZUVGTGRtaExNa3hIYkdJMllrcHZkbkJ6TjBGU1p6MDlPbWFXZ3IrNnZDMzI1MnZzVlVJU2hKQT0%3D'; return false;">download</button>
```

Link: https://games-database.com/1JD4?pt=ZUVGTGRtaExNa3hIYkdJMllrcHZkbkJ6TjBGU1p6MDlPbWFXZ3IrNnZDMzI1MnZzVlVJU2hKQT0%3D

This link is different everytime I refresh the page

It's easy to get this link with HTMLAgility Pack

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
var link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button")
                                                      .Select(p => p.InnerText).FirstOrDefault();
```

But when I try to download this I only get the page not the file

The working generated download link after the redirect looks like this:
https://dl5.cdnrobot.xyz/1JD4/Anomic_THE_NEW_GUI.txt?download_token=f58c9315280ed7474c15a329888ac8532e2af1cdaec045f4048bc51fcacd7e75

I don't know if the sites uses cookies or something else but maybe you can load the page in the background and then get the download link by tracking the redirects.

Thanks for everyone who wants to help!

I am on WPF .NET 6.0 btw

[EDIT]
I found a website called https://wheregoes.com and it manages to track the correct download URL

Then it tell me:
Status Code: 200 - Meta-Refresh Redirect

In conclusion I need a way to trace this redirect to get the download URL

Comment: You didn't post the code you are using to download the file.

Comment: I simply used WebClient to download from the url File but that obviously doesn't work